# How to group all requests in react and axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

How to group all requests in react and axios and wait for them to complete?

For example, I am sending three requests

```
axios.get('/posts'); // 1 req
axios.get('/users'); // 2 req
axios.get('/friends'); // 3 req
```

Only three requests on one page

How can I wait until all three are executed, and only then perform the action I need?

Comment: Wrap them in Promise.all, they return Promises.

Answer (score 1):

Every axios request returns a promise and you can use Promise.all method to wait for all of them to execute

```
Promise.all([axios.get('/posts'), axios.get('/users'), axios.get('/friends')]).then((values) => {
 console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [postsResults, userResults, friendResults]
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform multiple concurrent requests:

```js
function getPosts() {
  return axios.get('/posts');
}

function getUsers() {
  return axios.get('/users');
}

function getFriends() {
  return axios.get('/friends');
}

Promise.all([getPosts(), getUsers(), getFriends()])
  .then(function (results) {
    const posts = results[0];
    const users = results[1];
    const friends = results[2];
  });
```